# Setting popup to open every 30 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie which every 30 days (or any other set time period) will launch for example Stackoverflow.com.

I found an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926119/cookie-to-show-a-popup-every-30-days) which i thought might help.
and here is my test code so far:
The HTML + Initiator

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Load JQuery 1.8.3 and the repeatablePopup functions-->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/repeatablePopup.js"></script>

        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var visited = readCookie('visited');
                if (!visited || visited !== "true") {
                    createCookie('visited', "true", 7);
                } else {
                        window.open("http://stackoverflow.com");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Setting Cookie</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

The Funcitons on repeatablePopup.js

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    document.write('Cookie is set');
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Edit: problem now is that cookie is planted every time I refresh the page, even though the cookie exists.
So eventually the pop up isn't working.

Thanks for any help given,
Shahar

Comment: By the way, how are you checking that the cookie was "planted" in your computer?

Comment: I've removed all the cookies that were on it, and checking to see for a new cookie after I run the code. is it wrong way to do it? moreover the Firebug cookie section doesnt show anything.

Comment: More like it's a bit of a problematic way to do it. Normally I would check the headers that's all. I don't use Firebug so I have no idea. But, I can see it's working fine in Chrome

Comment: How do I check the headers as you mentiond? Do you think it'll work that after 7 days from the moment the cookie was planted it'll automatically popup a window of stackoverflow.com?

Comment: If it's not poping-up now then it's working, the cookie is being set. Ideally, it will. If the user doesn't delete its cookies. You can check the headers in the Network tab. For instance, you can check if you set a 1-minute cookie

Comment: You can check the cookies in Firefox's "View Page Info" window (then Details then View Cookies). I can see the cookie there with a 7day expiration time. To me it seems you're opening the pop up as long as the cookie is valid.

Comment: Well, I've changed it to 1 min, and waited for 2 minutes. It didn't poped up. :-/ any ideas? On the Network timeline it says sending. waiting and reciving are = 0

Comment: Jad, for testing porpuses I want to pop up as long as the cookie is valid, that's correct. yet even though the cookie is valid the link isn't pop up

Comment: This is cumbersome. [This fiddle works](http://jsbin.com/uwidah/31/edit). You just need to keep clicking "Run" until the cookie expires in 10 seconds

Comment: even in your fiddle, every time I run it the pop up is opening. it's recreating the cookie on every page load. I can see the cookie existing. but when the value is true the pop up coming up. (which it shouldnt occur as far as i understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (!readCookie('visited')) {
        window.open("http://stackoverflow.com");
        createCookie('visited', null, 30);
    }
});
```

When the cookie is not exist, then the pop-up window will opened. After the pop-up window opens, you set the cookie. Thirty days later, the cookie will expired and everything will back to normal and do the same thing again.

Comment: For some reason, it's seting a new cookie every time I load/refresh the page

Comment: Do you have a direct link to `js/repeatablePopup.js` ?

Comment: Managed to get it to work eventually, honestly I got no clue how.
Thanks for the solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [CoverPop.js](https://github.com/tylerpearson/CoverPop), maybe it help someone,,
there are some parameters that can be set

```
CoverPop.start({
    coverId:             'CoverPop-cover',       // set default cover id
    expires:             30,                     // duration (in days) before it pops up again
    closeClassNoDefault: 'CoverPop-close',       // close if someone clicks an element with this class and prevent default action
    closeClassDefault:   'CoverPop-close-go',    // close if someone clicks an element with this class and continue default action
    cookieName:          '_CoverPop',            // to change the plugin cookie name
    onPopUpOpen:         function() {},          // on popup open callback function
    onPopUpClose:        function() {},          // on popup close callback function
    forceHash:           'splash',               // hash to append to url to force display of popup (e.g. http://yourdomain.com/#splash)
    delayHash:           'go',                   // hash to append to url to delay popup for 1 day (e.g. http://yourdomain.com/#go)
    closeOnEscape:       true                    // close if the user clicks escape
    delay:               0                       // set an optional delay (in milliseconds) before showing the popup
    hideAfter:           null                    // set an optional time (in milliseconds) to autohide
});
```